# brightest amplitude of an image pixel

Tags: image-processing, matlab, python

How can amplitude of an image pixel be calculated?Do we need to perform any FFT on the image? and how to find the brightest value among the amplitudes in python or matlab?

Comment: Welcome at SE.DSP. If you could share some of your code, or thoughts, on how you would do this, that could be helpful

Comment: @Lauren Duval,Hi Im still researching on it.I need to calculate 2D frequency center, 2D spectrum width and 2D Delay in order to calculate an complex amplitude of an pixel using FFT..any idea on it would be helpful

Comment: Ah OK, this clears it up a little. I understand now that in the frequency domain, you are looking for 1) something like the location of the most visible frequency 2) its spread. That seems to me quite a different question, expect for the max. Is that correct (and I have update with Matlab and Python commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A discretized amplitude is directly obtained by the numerical value of an intensity attached to the pixel location. The brightest would the maximum intensity over the whole picture. It seems that in Python with `numpy` you get gt it as:

```
brightest = numpy.amax(imageData)
```

and in Matlab

```
brightest = max(imageData(:))
```